# In nuxt projects values from _variables.scss are not applied

Tags: sass, nuxt.js

In my nuxt project I added scss support with command

```
npm i -D @nuxtjs/style-resources sass-loader node-sass
```

components/scss/_variables.scss has :

and created file components/scss/main.scss with lines:

```
$link_color: #246647; 
$action_color: #3f5e5d; 

.title {
  //background-color: green !important; // IF TO UNCOMMENT THIS LINE IT IS APPLIED

  background-color: $link_color !important; // THESE 2 LINES ARE NOT APPLIED
  color: $action_color !important;
}
```

in  nuxt.config.js :

```
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/style-resources'],
    styleResources: {
      scss: [
        'components/scss/_variables',
        'components/scss/main.scss', //components/scss/main.scss
      ]
    },


  build: {
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  }
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "ntasks",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My stylish Nuxt.js project",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.9.0",
    "@nuxtjs/moment": "^1.4.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "store": "^2.0.12",
    "vee-validate": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

How correct to apply values from _variables.scss ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, but I dropped nuxt